# jQuery UI Dialog not opened for second time

Tags: html, jquery-ui, modal-dialog

jQuery UI Dialog not opened for second time

I have series of data as below

### html

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="popup_1" pop_val="abc" >Dummy Text</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="popup_1" pop_val="vbg" >Dummy Text</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="popup_1" pop_val="aere" >Dummy Text</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="popup_1" pop_val="vbb" >Dummy Text</a>


<div id="dialog" title="TEST MODAL">
    Loading...
</div> <!-- dialog -->
```

### jQuery

### Script One

This one runs perfect

```
<script>
$(".popup_1").bind('click', function (e) {


    var pop_value = $(this).attr("pop_val");
    console.log(pop_value);

    $("#dialog").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            width: 700,
            modal: true,
    });

    $("#dialog").dialog("open");


});
</script>
```

### Script Two

This script, runs for the first time and second time its not working,
instead it gives an error

> Uncaught TypeError: Object [object HTMLAnchorElement] has no method
>   'attr'
>
> [ var pop_value = $(this).attr("pop_val"); ]

```
<script>
$(".popup_1").bind('click', function (e) {


    var pop_value = $(this).attr("pop_val");
    console.log(pop_value);

    $("#dialog").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            width: 700,
            modal: true,
    });


    $.post("ajx_page.cfm?PID="+pop_value, {}, function(return_data){
        $("#dialog").html(return_data);
    });

    $("#dialog").dialog("open");

});
</script>
```

I have no clue, why it throws an error. I have gone throught other question on SO, but could not get perfect solution.

Comment: jQuery version? Actually your custom attribute is __pop_value__ not __pop_val__

Comment: Aside the 404 on the post works fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/7WFuq/

Comment: Its working good, when wrong page is set, but when i give a correct address, its not working. Its the same error `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object HTMLAnchorElement] has no method 'attr' `

Comment: It seems that it's because your this reference is not a jquery object, what jQuery version are you using? Are your elements dynamically added to the DOM?

Comment: jQuery Version `1.10.2` , Yes!, these are added by dynamically with `Coldfusion`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45616/discussion-between-rafee-and-irvin-dominin-aka-edward)